# How to update navbar after a successful login in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navbar

I am trying to "re-render" my navbar after the user logs in from the login page. I have certain nav links that will show depending on whether or not the user is logged.

Right now I am rendering those if I can find an user item on the localStorage:

`

```
Navbar.vue
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            notLoggedInDropDown: false,
            loggedInDropDown: false,
            logged: localStorage.getItem('user') == null ? false : true,
            user : {} 
        }
    },
    methods: {
        closeSession() {
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            this.logged = false;
            this.user = {};
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        this.user = user;
    },
}
</script>
```

`And this is what I do after I login from the login page:`

```
Login.vue
 methods: {
        async signIn(){
            try {
                const data = await login(this.username, this.password)
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.user))
                localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
                this.$router.push('/')
            } catch (error) {
                this.error.status = true
                this.error.message = "Username or password failed."
            }
        }
    },
```

`

I have tried to send emitters using mitt but navbar is not really a child component of the login page. I also have tried making the logged boolean a computed statement but it still does not re-render. I know that the reason it does not update is because the router.push method is not reactive, but I am unsure about what to try next. Also, my app does not use Vuex at the moment, can I integrate that easily into my Vue app? Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use Vuex.

Create a variable in vuex, write it from `Login.vue` and export it to all components throuht a getter. From `Navbar.vue` you should get the vuex variable in a computed property and react to its value change when somebody logs in.

Otherwise, the recommended way to handle a login is through vue-router, you should take a look at the vue docs for it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are three solutions I know to work.

- One is not rerouting with the `vue-router` but with the browser's functionality. Something like `location.replace(url);`.
- Two is working by `emitting` from the login page to the application and then using a `prop` giving the information to the navbar.
- Three and what i usually prefer using `vuex` to get a shared store between components.

Option one is the easiest and fastest, but option three makes your application more robust.